# Bind particular item as last item in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I am fetching records from the database. I want that a particular record always comes as the last element. How can I do this?

For eg:
From database:
A
B
C
D

But, I want "B" to come always in last. I want this:
A
C
D
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Column 
FROM   Table
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN  Column='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, Column
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is also help you...

```
create table #tbl(Name varchar(10))
Insert into #tbl values('A')
Insert into #tbl values('B')
Insert into #tbl values('C')
Insert into #tbl values('D')

SELECT Name
FROM   #tbl
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN  Name='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
Drop table #tbl
```